# How to use and setup Stripe Connect/Express to transfer incoming funds from one Stripe account to a separate Stripe account?

Tags: stripe-payments

[This is a flow diagram to explain what we are trying to do, looking for guidance for the best way to set this up. Will be extremely grateful to those helping to find a solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x920j.png)

Comment: Can you explain the flow of funds in words as well, rather than the diagram? Who pays whom in what amounts, where does your company collect fees, etc. You also likely should just ask [Stripe](https://support.stripe.com/email) directly as they help with these questions every day.

Comment: Yes absolutely, there are three parties here, The Agency (us), the Client, and the Customers. The Customer will pay the Client, and at the end of the day or whenever, we will collect 20% of whatever is in their account at the end of that day. We would only take 20% of each new purchase, so it would not be 20% day after day if they had no new purchases. Stripe notified us that we need a developer to assist with the API integration and to set the proper parameters.

Comment: Also we are using Stripe Connect Express accounts right now, if you or anyone you know has done this please feel free to share this thread with them, thank you!

Comment: The docs on this are [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges). You basically have two options: Direct Charges put the funds from each transfer into the balance of the connected account and take a fee to your own account, or Destination Charges put the funds into your account and then transfer the desired amount (e.g. everything except  your fee) to the connected account.